# Attributes are displayed 2 times when i use @jsonPropretyorder in Java

Tags: rest, api

I am developping Rest API using Spring Boot, I want to have a response such desired result
[image]

but when I run my API this is the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jONDd.png)

I search and I found that by using the annotation @JsonPropertyOrder we can order proprety.I use but this is the result:
[The result using json annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYBRV.png)

I don't understand why fields are diplayed 2 times.
This is my class and how I use the annotation: [Class customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FryTA.png)

Comment: the difference is the upper and lower case. Can you show your class and the @JsonPropertyOrder?

Comment: I respected the lower and upper case

Comment: please show the code otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: i edit the post and i put my class